# C# Quartz.Net Scheduler job not executing if it has got parameterised constructor

Tags: c#-4.0, quartz.net, topshelf

I am using C# Quartz.Net to create a scheduled job and make it as a windows service using TopShelf.

The scheduled job is not executing if the class contains a parameterised constructor. I am using Unit for Dependency Injection.

Can anyone help me what is the problem?

Here is the sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        IScheduler scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleJob>()
            .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
}

public class SimpleJob : IJob
{
    public SimpleJob(IRepository repo) { } //If i comment out this line, then it works.
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, JOb executed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation for IJob](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/4fc0f1b6-401d-a7aa-224c-c2fd34cec94e.htm)

> Instances of this interface must have a public no-argument constructor

By defining your constructor, the compiler assumes you no longer want the default constructor.

What is the point of this special constructor? (It won't be used by Quartz.)

If you need this constructor for some other purpose, then you also need to explicitly include the default constructor which Quartz can then use.

Comment: I tried including the default constructor as well. Not working. I basically trying to inject something using Unity into this job.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to get quartz to ask unity to create the job for you, rather than let quartz create it directly. If so, you can not use the standard factory, but something like  [Quartz.Unity](https://github.com/hbiarge/Quartz.Unity) (I haven't used it myself, so can't help further)

Comment: yes.i am using Quartz.unity. I think because there was some error resolving one of the dependency, the constructor with parameters was not called. now it is working

Answer (score 1):

We were able to implement this as mentioned above having our own JobFactory.  We wanted to treat our jobs as any other class using our IOC implementation to provide the dependencies the jobs need.

Here is our implementation:

```
    public class ContainerJobFactory : PropertySettingJobFactory
    {
        private readonly IContainer container;

        public ContainerJobFactory(IContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            var job = container.GetInstance(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
            if (ReferenceEquals(job, null))
                return base.NewJob(bundle, scheduler);
            SetObjectProperties(job, bundle.JobDetail.JobDataMap);
            return (IJob) job;
        }
    }
```

Here is how we plugged in our JobFactory:

```
 scheduler.JobFactory = new ContainerJobFactory(StaticContainer.Instance);             
 await scheduler.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that Quartz.Net requires a parameter-less constructor.  And that's that.

Since you look look like you want to INJECT, here is an article I had bookmarked.

http://blog.goyello.com/2009/09/21/how-to-use-quartz-net-in-pro-way/

The key information line is

*"You may want to create your own implementation of JobFactory to accomplish things such as having your application’s IoC or DI container produce/initialize the job instance."*